# antonyms in wordnet dictionary using JAWS api

Tags: java, wordnet

How to find antonyms in wordnet dictionary using JAWS api. is there any inbuilt function in the JAWS api.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is:

```
WordNetDatabase database = WordNetDatabase.getFileInstance();
Synset[] synsets = database.getSynsets(word);
for(Synset synset : synsets){
    WordSense[] wordsenses = synset.getAntonyms(word)
    for(WordSense wordsense : wordsenses) {
            addWordSenseToOntology(englishOntology, wordsense);
        }
}
```